# Command line utility to fetch MSI files tables

Tags: windows-installer, orca

Is there and command line utility similar to what does ORCA.exe?
I mean rather than using GUI like ORCA.exe or lessmsi, if I can find command line utility which can provide information about target MSI tables.

Thanks.

Comment: Not really. What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: As part of automation i am trying to read tables data.

Comment: Tell me your automation, what language is it written in?  There are ways to programmatically query and MSI database without dropping to a command line.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I'm aware of that comes close to that is msidb.exe which has a command line option to export the tables to text files, but the format isn't very readable.

Comment: There's also msi2xml which is even less readable but easily parsed.